# how to compare delphi exe

Tags: delphi, exe

I am having the two delphi generated exe of same project. One exe is generated long time ago and the second exe is generated recentaly using the current source code. Now there is difference in size between these two exe. Is there any way to find out why the size is different and to find way if any new functionality added to new exe by mistake. As exe is in binary. can we convert into any readable format? Or any other tips/comments? Thanks for help.

Note: I dont have the source code from which 1st exe is generated. So cant compare the source code. :(

Comment: Were the two executables created with the same version of Delphi? Modern Delphis produces larger executables. How big a size difference is there? How can you not have the original source code? Do you not use revision control? Since you don't have the original source code why do you even care about the old exe?

Comment: Yes both exe developed using same version and the size dierance is about 10kb between 2 exes. We use revision control but the code is not checked in by person who modified long time back. :(  As all business uses that original source code exe. So trying to ceate duplicate of original so that i can add new functionality on top of that.

Comment: Hard to see you getting very far with this. You can't even know how the exe was built, what the compiler options were and so on. Try decompiling the two executables and look at the differences. Then you might realise the magnitude of your task! If I were you I would work with the source code and code up the logic that you desire. If you are relying on a program that you don't understand and have no idea what it is doing, you are in terrible shape. Take back control.

Comment: I m working on new source code onwards but want to check i there is any way to compare exe. other wise i have no option other than using this new source code. I am almost sure about the source code is equivalent. But i am not sure about project options used while building the the old one. thanks for ur comment.

Comment: Another factor that can affect exe size is 3rd party libraries. You can re-compile the same source and get different results, if you have upgraded components or libraries along the way.  i.e. before, you had VCLZip 3.0, now you have 4.5.  With no other source code changes, if your app uses VCLZip, the size will be different.

Comment: yes thats i agree, but it will cause any error runtime?

Comment: You should find the differences using your source control software and who cares if the EXE file sizes are different? Even signing the file changes the file size.

Comment: @MarcusAdams According to comments above the exe was built with unknown code

Comment: Comparing exes is pointless, especially the other exe is build long time ago with unknown source and compiler settings. Anything could happened since long time ago. Even if you can compare both exes, what values can you get? Remember, their are exes, not source code. Instead of that, it is more valuable to do functional test on both exes.

Comment: can I extract the compiler settings or prject coniguration file from exe??

Comment: No you can't.  10kb difference is probably a different version of a component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **turbodiff** from http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=turbodiff to see the differences between two executables. Of course you will also need the freeware version of **IDA 5.0**, you can download that from http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml

Answer (score 2):

There are tools out there that will disassemble a native Intel x86 or x64 executable and spit out text assembler instructions, but since very little text from the original source code is preserved when compiling to native code, this disassembler produced text will most likely be machine generated alphabet soup. Mechanically correct but humanly gibberish.

You could try disassembling both the new and the old exe to asm text, then using a text diff tool to compare the differences between the asm texts. This will help reduce the diff tool noise of a small change creating a huge diff log because the small change causes all the global offsets to change after it.  The disassembled asm text should have fewer global offset dependencies.

The hard truth is, if you don't have a person who understands Intel asm instructions and the Delphi compiler code gen patterns, even this disassembly step is not likely to produce much useful information to help you understand why the two exes are different sizes. In a non-trivial app of, say, 500k in exe size, a 10k difference could be caused by compiling with different compiler options, such as with stack frames vs remove stack frames, or compiled in debug mode vs non-debug mode.

Even adding a reference in the new exe to Writeln() could account for most of that 10k - the text IO routines in the RTL are smart-linked out of your exe unless something uses it, and touching Writeln touches a whole forest of support routines inside the RTL. If the old exe didn't use Writeln but the new exe does, the new exe will be carrying the Writeln support routines which I vaguely recall weigh in at "more than a few K".